# Unable to include 3rd party node-modules in React native application

Tags: module, npm, react-native

I'm trying to understand how to import or require (not sure which! but I've tried both with the same result) node-modules into my react-native project.

Specifically I'm trying to include node-craigslist.

I'm met with the following error:

```
(node:82382) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2491): UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module url from /Users/fogonthedowns/hack/js/react-native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/node-craigslist/dist/index.js: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
  /Users/fogonthedowns/hack/js/react-native/AwesomeProject/node_modules
,   /Users/fogonthedowns/node_modules

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
```

My version of react is:

```
~/hack/js/react-native/AwesomeProject$ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.40.0
```

**My index.ios.js is** [here](https://gist.github.com/fogonthedowns/d69ca619180b0e03cf86d7ed608d070f).

I've tried everything. All of the advice in the feedback, I've even tried installing node-craigslist globally:

```
npm install -g node-craigslist
```

And then rebuilding from scratch. node-craigslist is clearly included in my node-modules folder. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**How can I include node-modules into a react native application?**

**What is the difference between require and import, in this case?**

**How can I include node-craigslist into a react native application without error?**

Answer (score 0):

Regression was [introduced in React Native 0.39](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11301) to packager. Try to restart packager server.
If this will not help then follow instruction from error description:

> 1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
> 2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
> 3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.

`import` is just like modern (es2015) version of `require`.

Comment: "I've tried everything. All of the advice in the feedback, I've even tried installing node-craigslist globally:" Thanks, but those do not work.

Comment: If you are using linux try also remove `react-native*` from `/tmp`: `rm -rf /tmp/react-native*`